# Creating a Parent object whose HABTM accepts_nested_attributes_for children is ignoring the association(children) attributes update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many, cocoon-gem

My ActiveRecord Models:

```
class Parent < AR
  has_and_belongs_to_many :children
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class Child < AR
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parents
end
```

The controller for Parent creating.
[EDITED]

```
def new
  current_child = current_user.set_child #first or initialize
  @parent = current_user.parents.build
  @parent.child_ids = [current_child.id].compact
  @children = [current_child]
end

def create
  @parent = current_user.parents.build(parent_params)
  if @parent.save
    ...
  else
    @children = @parent.children
    render :new
  end
end
```

[/EDITED]

```
def parent_params
  params.require(:parent).merge( child_ids: params[:parent][:children_attributes].map{|p,v| v[:id]} ).
  permit(:id, :picture, :remove_picture, child_ids: [],
  children_attributes: [ :id, :user_id, :full_name, :_destroy ] )
end
```

[EDITED]

The simple form for parent:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :children, @children do |child|
   = render 'child_fields', f: child
```

child fields file:

```
= f.hidden_field :id, value: f.object.id
= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: f.object.user_id
...
```

[/EDITED]

The point is that when Parent is saved, children_parents join table is update (nice), children table has no id children inserted (nice), **BUT if the children already has an ID (persisted), children table does not perform the update on them**

Debugging the prev line before `@parent.save`, is possible to ensure that `@parent.children` contains the children new attributes. Executed the command  `@parent.save`, children attributes aren't updating , but if `save` is called again, it performs the children update.

What could be happening?

Comment: Why do you have the `child_ids` in your `parent_params`?

Comment: @nathanvda. Otherwise, create fails with, i.E, `@parent = current_user.parents.build(child_params)` raises `Couldn't find Child with ID=XXX for Parent with ID=`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `current_user.parents.build(parent_params)` ?? Can you show your controller code where you save it? That is not how you save an element with nested attributes. Imho the `child_ids` is not needed and the cause of your error (because 1 operation sets the nested children with content, and the other sets the nested children as references --thus losing the content-changes).

Comment: you are right, I mistyped (its `parent_params`), I'm going to edit the question with the controller code.

Comment: like you see the inclusion of a default child is necessary in parent creation @nathanvda

Comment: Just notice that outside fields_for file (child_fields), children has the user_id persisted, but inside this file, f.object returns a child with user_id 0

Comment: You are doing something weird in your `new` action. Also: sometimes you write `child_ids`, sometimes `children_ids`, you set/show a `user_id` yet it is not in your strong-parameters? You create a child dependent on the user before the parent? Very hard to be make sense of it all and be of help. Did you check the demo-project https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo ?

Comment: it already was, just omitted coz I thought user would has no relation with the initial trouble